# How to wait till a particular line appears in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is it possible to write a script that does not proceed till a given line appears in a particular file?

For example I want to do something like this:

```
CANARY_LINE='Server started'
FILE='/var/logs/deployment.log'

echo 'Waiting for server to start'
.... watch $FILE for $CANARY_LINE ...
echo 'Server started'
```

Basically, a shell script that watches a file for line (or regex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `q` flag while parsing the input via `sed`. Then `sed` will interrupt `tail` as soon as `Server started` appears in `/var/logs/deployment.log`.

```
  tail -f /var/logs/deployment.log | sed '/Server started/ q'
```

Another way to do the same thing

```
  ( tail -f -n0 /var/logs/deployment.log & ) | grep -q "Server Started"
```

Previous answer (works but not as efficient than this one)

<strike>We have to be careful with loops.</strike>

For example if you want to check for a file to start an algorithm you've probably have to do something like that:

```
  FILE_TO_CHECK="/var/logs/deployment.log"
  LINE_TO_CONTAIN="Server started"
  SLEEP_TIME=10
  while [ $(cat FILE_TO_CHECK | grep "${LINE_TO_CONTAIN}") ]
  do
      sleep ${SLEEP_TIME}
  done

  # Start your algorithm here
```

But, in order to prevent an infinite loop you should add some bound:

```
  FILE_TO_CHECK="/var/logs/deployment.log"
  LINE_TO_CONTAIN="Server started"
  SLEEP_TIME=10
  COUNT=0
  MAX=10
  while [ $(cat FILE_TO_CHECK | grep "${LINE_TO_CONTAIN}") -a ${COUNT} -lt ${MAX} ]
  do
      sleep ${SLEEP_TIME}
      COUNT=$(($COUNT + 1))
  done

  if [ ! $(cat FILE_TO_CHECK | grep "${LINE_TO_CONTAIN}") ]
  then
    echo "Let's go, the file is containing what we want"
    # Start your algorithm here
  else
    echo "Timed out"
    exit 10
  fi
```

Comment: `$(SLEEP_TIME)` should be `${SLEEP_TIME}`. There's no need to cat and pipe to grep. And uppercase variables are a bad habit.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I've already fixed the `${SLEEP_TIME}`. About the naming convention, you are right using lower case seems to be a better idea in order to not override an environment variable.

Comment: Isn't the logic in the while loop reversed? This will loop as long as grep finds something, and stop when it doesn't. How about something like `until grep -q string file ; do sleep 1s ; done`?

Comment: grep returns 0 when  it find a match, otherwise it returns 1.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: Indeed, but putting it inside `[ $() ]` means the exit value of `[` controls `while`, and it will simply test whether the output of the command (`$()`) is a non-empty string. You can try this with `if [ $( true ) ] ; then echo true ; fi`.

Answer (score 29):

```
tail -n0 -f path_to_my_log_file.log | sed '/particular_line/ q'
```

Comment: The accepted answer is full of errors.  This works wonderfully!  Thanks Miloš!

Comment: note that this assumes the line will appear at the end of the file. that is usually the case, but not always.

Comment: I can't get this to work. `tail` continues execution after `sed` matches the regex.
For me, this worked:
https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found

Comment: either you tail the entire file and then expect the line to already exist in the file, or you `tail -n0` and expect the line to appear after you started looking for it. either way, just `tail -f` is inconsistent. I'll add `-n0`.

Comment: If the `particular_line` could appear repeatedly across the log, one would do wise to only start looking from the point were the change one is interested in can start appearing. Something like `LINES=$( wc -l < logfile.log ); ... do-something-triggering-new-logs ... ; tail -n"+${LINES}" -f logfile.log | sed '/particular_line/ q'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
CANARY_LINE='Server started'
FILE='/var/logs/deployment.log'

echo 'Waiting for server to start'
grep -q $CANARY_LINE <(tail -f $FILE)
echo 'Server started'
```

Source: adapted from [How to wait for message to appear in log in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572414/how-to-wait-for-message-to-appear-in-log-in-shell)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this will also work if instead of `tail` we want to wait for specific line in `docker logs -f`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

canary_line='Server started'
file='/var/logs/deployment.log'

echo 'Waiting for server to start'

until grep -q "${canary_line}" "${file}"
do
  sleep 1s
done

echo 'Server started'
```

Adjust `sleep`'s parameter to your taste.

If the line in the file needs to match *exactly*, i.e. the whole line, change `grep`'s second parameter to `"^${canary_line}$"`.

*If* the line contains any characters that `grep` thinks are special, you're going to have to solve that... somehow.

Comment: Could lead into an infinite loop

Comment: Yes, it will run until the line appears in the file or until it is killed. I thought that's what OP wanted.

Comment: ...an *infinite loop*, if you ask me, is one out of which the program cannot get itself. And this isn't one of those.

Comment: Doesn't this grep the complete file over and over?