# How to wait for message to appear in log in shell

Tags: bash, shell

Could you please provide neat solution to block execution of the script until text snippet appear in the given file?

Comment: Depends aa lot on buffering and which operating system you are using.  Linux provides several non-standard interfaces based around `inotify` (`man 7 inotify`) but there is nothing in `bash` to do this.  Even `inotify` will only detect changes after a buffer has been flushed.  If the writing program uses large buffers then there could be no detectable change to the file size until the program closes (which usually flushes the buffers).  Note that killing a process with `-KILL` signal (`kill -9`) might result in buffers not being flushed and data loss.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wait forever

```
grep -q 'ProducerService started' <(tail -f logs/batch.log)
```

Wait with timeout

```
timeout 30s grep -q 'ProducerService started' <(tail -f logs/batch.log)
```

Wait with timeout, notify error

```
timeout 30s grep -q 'ProducerService started' <(tail -f logs/batch.log) || exit 1
```

Comment: How to show output and get logs ? When i use this, the command inside parentheses prevent showing any logs .

Answer (score 1):

Use `inotifywait` 
inotifywait efficiently waits for changes to files

example:-

1. kill the process to be blocked
2. `inotifywait -q -e modify /path/to/file/containing/snippet`
3. check for the changes in the file
4. if the change matches then restart the script